# Can't Commit Git, Git can't ID user

Tags: git

I'm using git on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit, I try to commit and I get this error:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'svetlana@svetlana-AO722.(none)')
```

I did all of this but it seems to see that my computer name has a @, how to correct this?

Comment: Git tells you exactly what to do to fix the issue...

Comment: Your computer name has a `?`... Can you provide the output of the commands you executed to configure git?

Comment: It's working now, coping and pasting helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

with a real email address. For example

```
git config --global user.email "pippo@gmail.com"
```